# How to return a table in SQL Server function

Tags: sql-server

How would I return a table from a SQL Server function?

In Postgres, I would simply do something like the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION table_get(_active_bool BOOLEAN)
RETURNS TABLE(column integer)
language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
         RETURN QUERY
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE active = _active_bool
END;
$$;
```

And it will just work.

For what ever reason I can't get this one to work in SQL Server.

```
CREATE FUNCTION hr.naughty_emp_id_get
    (@pquarter NVARCHAR(1),
     @pyear NVARCHAR(4))
RETURNS TABLE (employeeid INT)
AS
BEGIN
    WITH vars AS 
    (
         SELECT @pquarter AS pquarter, @pyear AS pyear
    )
    SELECT tblhr_employees.employeeid
    FROM hr.tblhr_employees
    INNER JOIN hr.tblHR_AttendancePunchTime ON tblhr_employees.employeeid       = tblHR_AttendancePunchTime.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN hr.tblHR_AttendanceTimeCode  ON tblHR_AttendancePunchTime.CodeID = tblHR_AttendanceTimeCode.CodeID
    WHERE 1 = 1
      AND (tblHR_AttendanceTimeCode.CategoryID = 3
           OR tblHR_AttendanceTimeCode.CategoryID = 11)
      AND dbo.to_year_quarter(tblHR_AttendancePunchTime.AdjTimeIn) = (SELECT vars.pyear FROM vars) + '-' + (SELECT vars.pquarter FROM vars)
      AND tblhr_employees.separationdate IS NULL
    GROUP BY 
        tblhr_employees.employeeid;

    RETURN
END
GO
```

It is throwing this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure naughty_emp_id_get, Line 18 [Batch Start Line 6]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'

I tried adding `;`s in various spots and it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the table name for the table to be returned. This should work

```
 CREATE FUNCTION hr.naughty_emp_id_get
 (
     -- Add the parameters for the function here
     @pquarter NVARCHAR(1)
   , @pyear NVARCHAR(4)
 )
 RETURNS @employees TABLE (employeeid INT)
 AS
 BEGIN
 WITH vars AS (SELECT @pquarter AS pquarter, @pyear AS pyear)
 INSERT @employees
 SELECT tblhr_employees.employeeid
 FROM hr.tblhr_employees
 INNER JOIN hr.tblHR_AttendancePunchTime ON tblhr_employees.employeeid       = tblHR_AttendancePunchTime.EmployeeID
 INNER JOIN hr.tblHR_AttendanceTimeCode  ON tblHR_AttendancePunchTime.CodeID = tblHR_AttendanceTimeCode.CodeID
 WHERE 1=1
 AND (tblHR_AttendanceTimeCode.CategoryID      = 3
 OR tblHR_AttendanceTimeCode.CategoryID       = 11)
 AND dbo.to_year_quarter(tblHR_AttendancePunchTime.AdjTimeIn) = (SELECT vars.pyear FROM vars) + '-' + (SELECT vars.pquarter FROM vars)
 AND tblhr_employees.separationdate IS NULL
 GROUP BY tblhr_employees.employeeid;

     RETURN
 END
```

Comment: It did thank you. It ran and I was able to successfully use the following select. `SELECT * FROM hr.naughty_emp_id_get('1','2018');`

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch If this works (and read the other suggestion - it is very important), then please accept it as the answer. That is how SO works, questions get asked and answered so others can find those answers.

Answer (score 3):

You have mixed 2 ways of declaring the resulting temporal table.

Either declare as table variable and explicitly insert into it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION hr.naughty_emp_id_get
(
    @pquarter NVARCHAR(1)
  , @pyear NVARCHAR(4)
)
RETURNS @result TABLE (employeeid INT) -- Here
AS
BEGIN
    ;WITH vars AS (SELECT @pquarter AS pquarter, @pyear AS pyear)
    INSERT INTO @result (employeeid) -- And here
    SELECT tblhr_employees.employeeid
    FROM --...

END
```

Or avoid it's declaration altogether:

```
CREATE FUNCTION hr.naughty_emp_id_get
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @pquarter NVARCHAR(1)
  , @pyear NVARCHAR(4)
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
    WITH vars AS (SELECT @pquarter AS pquarter, @pyear AS pyear)
    SELECT tblhr_employees.employeeid
    FROM --...
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is not merely a syntax difference. The second version creates an inline table-valued function, which can be expanded by the optimizer when invoked in queries and typically has better performance characteristics than the non-inline variant (although occasionally the opposite can be the case, depending on how the function is used).

Comment: Ideally what @JeroenMostert said is true, however Microsoft claims to have fixed this in SQL Server 2017 by adaptive query processing (https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=szTmo6rTUjM). I don't have an instance to verify this , but I will try and get back on this topic when I can

Comment: @SQLApostle: SQL Server 2017 improves things by allowing accurate cardinality estimates for multi-statement TVFs and changing the execution plan based on that, which will improve their characteristics in many scenarios. However, the basic difference between multi-statement and inline TVFs remains: inline TVFs are expanded in the query, multi-statement TVFs are materialized first. There's use cases for both; the improvements for MSTVFs mean they can now be better than inline TVFs in more cases (especially for complex queries), making it even more important to try both.

Comment: [Link to the docs with details](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/performance/adaptive-query-processing?view=sql-server-2017#interleaved-execution-for-multi-statement-table-valued-functions) for people who can't or don't want to watch videos.

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert into the resulting table variable.

```
RETURNS @MyTable TABLE (MyID INT)
AS BEGIN    
    INSERT INTO @MyTable SELECT 1
    RETURN 
END
```

Comment: I think you have a syntax error here... missing the `TABLE` after the variable.